# Problema com reprodução de vídeos usando tag nativa do HTML5

Tags: html5, vídeo, html5-video, reprodutor-de-video

Recentemente hospedei um arquivo de vídeo em `MP4` no meu servidor e utilizei a tag nativa do HTML5 para a reprodução da mídia no website. O som sai normalmente e o vídeo não é exibido (testei no meu PC e ele executa ambos, tanto áudio quanto vídeo).

Suspeito que o problema seja referente ao *buffer*, pois contém tamanho aproximado de 142MB (em torno de 1h16m de reprodução). Como posso solucionar esse problema?

Código HTML:

```
<video width="500" height="250" autoplay controls>
      <source src="meu_arquivo_mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente converter o video para mp4 mas desta vez usando o codec H.264

Video H.264
Audio AAC

[HTML5 Video Encoding](http://www.encoding.com/html5/)

Comment: Obrigado! Estarei convertendo, logo marco como solucionada.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação, tudo funcionou como esperado.